# Need Processing assistance. If statement

Tags: if-statement, processing, void, rect

Can someone help me with my code. I am trying to get the square to appear on the left side of the window again once it moves off the right side. I almost have it, but once it goes off the right side, it suddenly appears on the left side. I need help making it appear smoothly on the left side of the screen.

Here is my code.

```
float x = 0;
void setup() {
  size(200,200);
}
void draw() {
  background(255);
  drawRect();
  if(x > width+5) {
    x = 0;
 }
}
void drawRect() {
  fill(0);
  for (int i = 0; i<width; i+=15){
  rect(x +i*2,100,20,20);
}
  x = x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what the loop in `drawRect()` does, but it seems like you want to reset `x` such that the shape it draws is just off the left side of the screen, so something like this:

```
if (x > width+5) {
  x = -50;
}
```